# How to get the count of the current sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet that I have spread out over many sheets. However, **I could automate the filling out of some simple data by doing some simple calculations.** I could program something simple like this, but I have been looking at Google's function list, and I cannot see anything that would allow me to do this. Everything I need to automate needs access to the current sheet number.

So these are the properties of my spreadsheet...

- I have 7 different classes I am looping through, and each one of them
  have specific things that need to be done for the months of December,
  January, and February
- Each month is a new spreadsheet (Should be automated - 1 cell)

  - Sheet 1 - December   ----    NOTE: Sheet 1, 2, and 3 are for 1 Class (ie. DA - December)
  - Sheet 2 - January
  - Sheet 3 - February
  - Sheet 4 - December
  - Sheet 5 - January
  - etc..
- For each month, things are divided into 2 weeks. (Should be automated - 2 cells)

  - Sheet 1 - Week 1, Week 2
  - Sheet 2 - Week 3, Week 4
  - Sheet 3 - Week 5, Week 6
  - etc...
- For each month, there are only 6 items (3 items per week) (Should be automated - 6 cells)

  - Sheet 1 - Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, Day 4, Day 5, Day 6
  - Sheet 2 - Day 7, Day 8, Day 9, Day 10, Day 11, Day 12
  - etc...

**I have been trying to find functions that could allow me to do this, but I don't even know if it is possible.** I have seen that there **use to be** a script gallery, but that is not the add-on manager. I have not seen anything in there to solve my issue

---

I figured if I could get the current sheet count, then I could easily do this myself. Just apply a little algebra and some though and I could automate this process.

For the months, I can have a formula with modulus
 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc, and turn it into ...
 - 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, etc..

For the weeks, I can have a simple formula like

- = ([current sheet #] * 2)
- = ([current sheet #] * 2) - 1

For the days, I can have a simple formula like

- = ([current sheet #] * 6)
- = ([current sheet #] * 6) - 1
- ...
- = ([current sheet #] * 6) - 6

Comment: Why are you using several sheets instead of a single one?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have a fundamental design flaw if each month is a new sheet, and there is nothing on the sheet to show the current month.

I would suggest putting all the data onto one sheet, and then adding per-month extracts onto other sheets using the various summarisation and extraction tools  (pivot tables etc).

Comment: OK, let me explain more. I have 7 classes. Each class has stuff for Month 12, 1, and 2. So There are sheets Class 1 - 12, Class 1 - 1, Class 1 - 2, Class 2 - 12, Class 2 - 1, etc.... This works for me, so I don't see this as a design flaw. Just to clear it up.

Comment: So this is how the sheets will look like. December, January, February,  December, January, February,  December, January, February, etc... The Sheets will be named by "Class - Month". If I can get the current sheet number, then I can do a modulus plus some logic, and display the correct information in the sheet name and in a cell within the sheet. So, yes, there will be cell with the current month on every sheet

Answer (score 1):

At this time there isn't a built-in function that gives the number of sheets, so you have to think around the alternatives to [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en).

It's worth to say that sheets doesn't have an inherent number, so you should determine how do you will assign a number to each sheet. One way is to assign a numerical prefix as part of the sheet name.